# Handling Active MQ custom messages Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, activemq-classic

I have been struggling with handling ActiveMQ custom messages push.
I have a 3rd party software that pushes messages into ActiveMQ queue.
what should be the message structure like?
how can i read the message body in my job?

Comment: Any luck with your ActiveMQ journey?

Answer (score 0):

You can Enqueue like this

```
$sMessage = json_encode(
    array(
        'job' => 'path/to/your/job/file',
        'data' => $aDataToSend,
        'queue' => /queue/name/to/append,
        'attempts' => 1
    )
);
```

And can consume like this:

```
class JobClassName extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels, BaseJob;

    public function __construct()
    {}

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {}

    public function fire($oJob, $aData)
    {}
}
```